# iOS: Keep active UITextField in middle of the Screen while Keyboard is shown

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, scroll

I have a UITableViewController with some static cells (filled with UITextFields). Now I'd like to keep the active UITextField in middle of my Screen (even if I go one Cell/UITextfield up/down).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this a couple of times in the past, didn't like it very much though.
My solution was to move the view with the table up, so the selected cell can stay visible.

First I added some observers to know when the keyboard appeared or disappeared

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShowNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHideNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Then I did something like this, to push the table up:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShowNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {


    CGSize kbSize = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    double animationDuration = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGPoint newCenter = self.myable.center;

    NSLog(@"Height: %f Width: %f", kbSize.height, kbSize.width);
    // Portrait:    Height: 264.000000  Width: 768.000000
    // Landscape:   Height: 1024.000000 Width: 352.000000

    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] < 3) {
        newCenter = CGPointMake(newCenter.x, heightP - kbSize.height - self.myTable.frame.size.height/2);
    }
    else {
        newCenter = CGPointMake(newCenter.x, heightL - kbSize.width - self.myTable.frame.size.height/2);
    }



    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    self.myTable.center = newCenter;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHideNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"keyboard disappeared");
    double animationDuration = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGPoint newCenter = self.myTable.center;

    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] < 3) {
        newCenter = CGPointMake(newCenter.x, 0 + self.lmyTable.frame.size.height/2);
    }
    else {
        newCenter = CGPointMake(newCenter.x, 0 + self.myTable.frame.size.height/2);
    }



    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    self.myTable.center = newCenter;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Basically, I read the keyboard height and added it to the center of the table, to push it upwards, and then removed the same height when the keyboard disappeared.

Now, there is a catch!
I removed it from my code because it was very specific, but you have to be careful to move your table **only when the keyboard would cover your cell**! Otherwise you will end up pushing visible cells over the top of the screen.
This pretty much depends on your view setting, the borders, the size of the table and so on, so I can't help you on this part, but I hope you got the basic idea!

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler... in your tableview's delegate `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:<#(NSIndexPath *)#> atScrollPosition:<#(UITableViewScrollPosition)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>` to scroll to your cell. You might have to change your tableview's frame for this and change it back again when the cell gets deselected. Or us it's scroll insets property to scroll.

Comment: If the cell happens to be on the bottom of the table, it will remain there and will be covered by the keyboard. In the end, you still have to detect the keyboard willAppear/Disappear and adjust the frame accordingly. Trust me, been there, done that. Actually, it wast the first thing I tried when I struggled with this

Comment: I know your method works... Actually, if I'm not wrong, it is inspired from one of Apple's own solutions in one of their projects...can't remember which one exactly but i'm sure i saw a similar solution there although it was not in a tableView but in a scrollView (not much difference in my opinion)

Comment: I don't know about apple's solution, it might be. I came up with it myself after trying to find something similar in their UITableView API but I never thought it was a good solution, it seems rather forced and not elegant, but does the trick